# Python py2app with psutil module

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I have a Python application I am trying to make a standalone version of using py2app. However, when I execute the .app file it terminates with the following error

`ImportError: No module named _psutil_osx`

Here is a sample application (test.py) that has the same problem but that works fine when I run `python test.py`:

```
from psutil import cpu_percent
print cpu_percent()
```

Then I run the following from the terminal

```
py2applet --make-setup test.py
python setup.py py2app
```

Here is the error log from the console

```
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]:   File "/Users/MyUser/Documents/Python/testpy/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 320, in <module>
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]:     _run('test.py')
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]:   File "/Users/MyUser/Documents/Python/testpy/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 317, in _run
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]:     execfile(path, globals(), globals())
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]:   File "/Users/MyUser/Documents/Python/testpy/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/test.py", line 1, in <module>
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]:     from psutil import cpu_percent
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]:   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/psutil/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]:   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/psutil/_psosx.py", line 14, in <module>
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]: ImportError: No module named _psutil_osx
test[34841]: test Error
[0x0-0xd80d8].org.pythonmac.unspecified.test[34841]: Exited with code: 255
```

It seems to be importing psutil just fine but one of the sub-packages is _psutil_osx and that is not getting imported. Any idea why that wouldn't be included? I have tried adding that to my includes and requires in the setup.py file as well but to no avail. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the _psutil_osx module is a compiled shared library. You need to use py2app's frameworks option to include it.
“